# Char pointer throwing Access Violation

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I can't understand why this code is throwing an unhandled "Access Violation" exception. It's a simple program that attempts to copy one char pointer string to another while skipping some characters (chars at index: 3,4,5)

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
char str[20];
char *str1 = "abcdeabcde", *str2 = "";
int i, dx = 0;

for(i=0; *(str1+i)!='\0'; i++)
    if(i<3 || i>5)
    {
        *(str2 + dx) = *(str1 + i);
        dx++;
    }
*(str2+dx) = '\0';
cout<<str2;

_getch();
}
```

Whereas the assignment using syntax `*(str + i)` works fine in the following function code (it's an implementation of getline)

```
int getstr(char *str, int n)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n && (ch = _getch())!= '\r'; i++)
    {
        if(ch == '\b')
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                i = -1; continue;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"\b \b";
                i -= 2;
            }
        }
        else if(ch > 31 && ch < 127 && i<n-1)
        {
            cout<<ch;
            *(str + i) = ch;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\a";
            i--;
        }
    }
    *(str + i) = '\0';
    return i+1;
}
```

So why does this work in the second case but not in first?

Comment: `std::string newstr(oldstr); newstr.erase(3,3);` does the job if you're not prohibited from STL assets.

Comment: If you used a standard compliant compiler, it would have told you that `char *str1 = "abcdeabcde", *str2 = ""` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why does this work in the second case but not in first?

Because in the first case, these are literal strings `char *str1 = "abcdeabcde", *str2 = "";` and you are not allowed to change the content of either `str1` and `str2`

This is a well-known undefined behavior in C/C++. See this list: [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a)

in particular this line:

- Attempting to modify a string literal or any other const object during its lifetime (UB)

Comment: Dôh! You beat me by a second.

Answer (score 2):

Here lies your problem:

```
*(str2 + dx) = *(str1 + i);
```

`str2` is a pointer to a string literal. You can read from `str2` as long as you don't read past its NUL character, but you are not allowed to write in it, since the compiler might store the string literal in a specific and read-only section of your binary.

Here, you write to `str2` past its end. This is a double undefined behaviour!